# Creating a System Sequence Diagram from an [extended] use case

Tags: java, design-patterns, mvc

As I have been taught - one controller = one use case.

But I have:

- OutsiderController
- SupplierController (which extends OutsiderController)
- SubContractorController (which also extentds OutsiderController)

And I want to do the SSD for `SupplierController` and `SubContractorController`. What do I do? Do I write in both SSDs the methods from `OutsiderController`?

Comment: SSD would mean System Sequence Diagram, I shall edit my question. I just thought that considering it is a question about an use case, mvc and design patterns, SSD will be understand as diagram and not a disc

Comment: Never assume an acronym will be understood. I know my fair share about use cases, mvc, design patterns and sequence diagrams, but it hadn't occurred to me that SSD would mean system sequence diagram. It simply isn't the first thing that comes into my mind when seeing the acronym. Making people work/think to understand your question simply may actually prevent you from getting the answer you seek. If you want people to help, make it as easy as possible for them to do so.

Comment: Yes I understand that @Marjan I just thought it is widely used as we had studied it as a main part of design patterns, I am no more making this mistake :-)

Comment: No problem. Everybody suffers from the expectation that others magically know what is on our screen, in our mind and we start talking/writing from that assumption. Goodness knows I have fallen into that trap often enough. :-D

Answer (score -1):

Providing one System Sequence Diagram (SSD)  will be enough if all the Controllers do the same flow with minor differences